# React state is not being re-rendered after change

Tags: reactjs

**What do I have:**
React container

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState({
    0: {
      category: "category1",
      count: 0
    }
  });
  const checked = (e, category) => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(() => {
        let tmp = items;
        tmp[0].count++;
        console.log(tmp[0].count);
        setItems(tmp);
        console.log(items[0].count);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h3>
        Progress: {items[0].category} - {items[0].count}
      </h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          task 1
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={(e) => {
              checked(e, items[0].category);
            }}
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          task 2
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={(e) => {
              checked(e, items[0].category);
            }}
          />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-fire-zbroc?file=/src/App.js)

**What do I want to achieve:** update counter on success `axios` request.

```js
//axios
      .then(() => {
        let tmp = items;
        tmp[0].count++;
        console.log(tmp[0].count); //this logs expected value
        setItems(tmp);
        console.log(items[0].count); //this logs expected value
      })
```

For some reason, rendered `count` value in

```html
      <h3>
        Progress: {items[0].category} - {items[0].count}
      </h3>
```

is not being updated and is always `0`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate your state like that:

```
let tmp = items;
tmp[0].count++;
```

You should use other methods to update your state. Since your state is an object you can use something like that:

```
setItems((prev) => ({
  ...prev,
  0: {
    ...prev["0"],
    count: prev["0"].count + 1,
  },
}));
```

I couldn't quite understand your intention. Don't you want to keep the `items` as an array then render them by using `map` maybe?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to keep `items` as an array, but I left them as the are just for simplicity

Comment: Ok then, you should always use methods and your own ways which do not mutate the state.

Answer (score 0):

Right now in your function you are directly mutate the state when you do

```
let tmp = items;
tmp[0].count++;
```

Never directly mutate the component state. You should create a copy of the state like below and this will fix your bug

```
let tmp = {...items};
tmp[0].count++;
```

Comment: This also mutates the state. Spread syntax only makes shallow copies.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. For deep object it still mutate the property inside